# Create multiple zip files that are not dependent on each other?

Tags: windows, compression, zip

I want to compress a folder into multiple zip files of 50MB each but don't want them to be dependent on each other. When I use Winzip and use the split feature it creates one zip file and the others are just continuation to it. So, that means I need all of the files to unzip the folder.

I want to unzip each file separately and I don't care if the files are of varied sizes as long as they are less than 50MB.

Comment: Yea now that is a challenge man! I dont wanna ask why, but the onluy way is to make separate folder.. Ha.. makes sense.. You will need a script or something to do it auto.

Comment: You coul;d do it through trial and error... Select 55mb/60mb of files, zip them and check the filesize, if it's below then great, do the next set - if it isn't select a few less and try again.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I already said :)

Comment: You can extract the contents of part zips with no problem. Each part contains the full list though, so what will get extracted is hit and miss.

Comment: It would be fairly easy, in, say, Java, to write a program that would guestimate compression based on file type and generate zip files with a "target" size, not always guaranteeing to do it perfectly.  Then, if you added a trial-and-error feature you probably could approximate "perfect".  SMOP.

Answer (score 2):

WinZip (or any modern compressing software) can't know before compressing what will be the size of compressed data. On top of that, the size of a compressed file would change (by a tiny bit) depending of the nearby files data. 
So if that's not theoretically impossible, WinZip is not able to do this nor any data compression software I know of, as it would involve compressing the data many times to get the closer matches.
Your best hope is to manually select groups of files and compress them to get ~50MB files. And when I write "manually", you may want to try writing a script doing the work for you. But I guess 50MB is not a hard limit, and you could just use the approximation method by hand.

Comment: You answer is overly verbose.  Further it focuses on a detail that has little bearing.  His size caveat was an afterthought to his being able to manipulate each individual segment of the archive as a functional whole unto itself.

Comment: +1 for courtesy. i don't downvote very often (and am not now, on any of these answers - but only on principle), but i'll upvote civility any day. unfortunately those days are becoming far & few between.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SpinZip](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/spinzip-create-zip-files-with-custom-file-count-or-archive-size/) to create multiple independent zip files with defined sizes.

Answer (score -1):

Not happening boss.  The ONLY way you could do this would be to simply Zip each individual archive that you want to be fully functional on it's own.  All there is to it.