# Create zip files that with given size

Tags: bash, centos, zip

My question is same as in [Create multiple zip files that are not dependent on each other?](https://superuser.com/questions/368669/create-multiple-zip-files-that-are-not-dependent-on-each-other) but my idea is to add files to zip until it is of required size and continue with a new zip file for others and so on.

Any idea how to do this in a bas script? The script here, https://superuser.com/questions/614176/creating-a-bash-script-zipping seems to of much help. Needs some customizations though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic script would just check the zip file's size and switch zip files accordingly. Something like this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## This counter is used to change the zip file name
COUNTER=0;
## The maximum size allowed for the zip file
MAXSIZE=1024;
## The first zip file name
ZIPFILE=myzip"$COUNTER".zip;
## Exit if the zip file exists already
if [ -f $ZIPFILE ]; then
    echo $ZIPFILE exists, exiting...
    exit;
fi
## This will hold the zip file's size, initialize to 0
SIZE=0;

## Go through each of the arguments given in the command line
for var in "$@"; do
    ## If the zip file's current size is greater than or
    ## equal to $MAXSIZE, move to the next zip file
    if [[ $SIZE -ge $MAXSIZE ]]; then
    let COUNTER++;
    ZIPFILE=myzip"$COUNTER".zip;
    fi
    ## Add file to the appropriate zip file
    zip -q $ZIPFILE $var;
    ## update the $SIZE
    SIZE=`stat -c '%s' $ZIPFILE`;
done
```

**CAVEATS:**

- The script expects *files*, not directories, if you want it to run on directories add `-r` to the `zip` command. However, it will not check the file size until *each* directory has been compressed.
- The zip file's size is checked *after* each compression. This means that you will get files that are larger then your limit. This because it is hard to guess what a file's compressed size will be so I can't check before adding it to the archive.

Comment: Well, that was cool. I just hacked a script inspired from this answer. Will update my question with the new script.

Comment: @Aczire please don't. Post your script as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Any idea about optimizing the below script for huge file counts??

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

format="%b-%m.zip"    # the default format
# see http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date
dateformat="%Y-%b-%d" # the default date format
zipsize=2048; #256901120 #245MB
zipfile="" # the zip file name to use.

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 directory [format] [zip size] [dateformat]"
  echo
  echo "Where format can include the following variables:"
  echo " %f file"
  echo " %b file with no extention"
  echo " %e file extention"
  echo " %c file created date (may be 1-Jan-1970 UTC if unknown)"
  echo " %m file modified date"
  echo " %t current date"
  echo
  echo "And dateformat uses the same format specifiers as the date command."
  echo
  echo " Example: $0 zip-1 %f-%m.zip %Y"
  echo " Example: $0 zip-1 %f-%m.zip %Y-%b"
  echo
  echo "And zipsize is the maximum zip size allowed per zip file in bytes."
  echo
  echo " Example: $0 zip-1 256901120 %f-%m.zip %Y"
  echo " Example: $0 zip-1 256901120 %f-%m.zip %Y-%b"
  exit 1
fi

if [[ $# -ge 2 ]]; then
  zipsize="$2"
fi

if [[ $# -ge 3 ]]; then
  format="$3"
fi

if [[ $# -ge 4 ]]; then
  dateformat="$4"
fi


dozip()
{
  filepath=$1
  parent_path=$(dirname "$filepath")
  file=$(basename "$filepath")
  ext=${file##*.}
  body=${file%.*}

  date=$(date +$dateformat)
  mdate=$(date --date="@$(stat -c %Y "$filepath")" +$dateformat)
  cdate=$(date --date="@$(stat -c %W "$filepath")" +$dateformat)

    if [ -z "$zipfile" ]; then
    zipfile=$(echo $format | sed -e "s/%f/$file/g" -e "s/%b/$body/g" -e "s/%e/$ext/g" -e "s/%t/$date/g" -e "s/%m/$mdate/g" -e "s/%c/$cdate/g")
    else
    size=`stat -c '%s' $zipfile`
    if [[ $size -ge $zipsize ]]; then
      zipfile=$(echo $format | sed -e "s/%f/$file/g" -e "s/%b/$body/g" -e "s/%e/$ext/g" -e "s/%t/$date/g" -e "s/%m/$mdate/g" -e "s/%c/$cdate/g")
    fi
    fi

  pushd "$parent_path" > /dev/null
  zip "$zipfile" "$file" > /dev/null
  popd > /dev/null
}

#files=$(find $1 -type f)
files=$(find $1 -type f | sed -e '/zip$/d') # exclude zip files
IFS=$'\n';
for file in $files; do
  dozip $file
done
```

Comment: The best thing to do for huge file counts is probably adding everything to a single zip and then `split`ing.

Comment: @teredon if that was feasible in this case, my life would be much easier :) Sadly, each zip file goes to different users. I was trying to add a checkpoint count like 1000, add files till the count, check the size etc.. But without much performance gain.